# QTextEdit ничего не выводит после переопределения keyPressEvent

Tags: qt, ruby

```
require 'Qt4'

class Test<Qt::TextEdit
    def keyPressEvent(e)
        if(e.key()==Qt::Key_Enter || e.key==Qt::Key_Return)
            puts "Ok"
        end
    end
end

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)

ptxt1=Test.new
ptxt2=Test.new
ptxt3=Test.new

spl1=Qt::Splitter.new(Qt.Vertical)
spl2=Qt::Splitter.new(Qt.Horizontal,spl1)
spl1.addWidget(ptxt1)
spl2.addWidget(ptxt2)
spl2.addWidget(ptxt3)

spl1.resize(500, 500)
spl1.show()
spl2.show()
app.exec()
```

Программа должна при нажатии Enter при фокусе в нижнем QTextEdit печатать "Ok" в консоль, это она делает, но при этом в нижний QTextEdit не получается что-либо напечатать. В чем ошибка? Думаю дело в keyPressEvent. Я новичек, поэтому прошу не пинать сильно.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю ruby, но в Вашем коде я не вижу, чтобы Вы отдавали управление базовому классу(TextEdit) на обработку тех клавиш, что Вас не интересуют. Сейчас Вы просто обрабатываете Enter, а остальное уходить в «чёрную дыру»

---

Вот как это можно сделать в C++:

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || event->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
    {
        //Что-то делаем
        //...
        //Если мы хотим чтобы QTextBox тоже обработал enter, тогда надо закомментировать return
        return;
    }
    QTextBox::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Согласен. А вы не можете привести код, скажем, на С++ или Python, делающий то, о чем Вы говорите?

Comment: @Евгений, обновил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду разбираться, как это можно перевести на руби

Comment: @Евгений, когда решите проблему и если мой ответ поспособствует этому, не забудьте принят ответ(галочка рядом с ответом)

Comment: @Евгений, на Python должно быть что-то похожее на `QtGui.QTextBox.keyPressEvent(self, event)`